# How to avoid ng-repeat repopulate unaffected data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

What's a good way to solve this?

I have a list of items on user's view. Each item could be expaned - only one at a time. (I'm using Angular Bootstrap Accordion). In the expanded container I have a password input. The problem is that I'm updating the item list every 20 secs, and the list might be repopulated exactly when the user is entering the password, and everything gets totally messed up.

*Imagine this like a list of WiFi Networks - with continuous scanning.

Comment: If you are updating the list every 20 secs, Can the user change the data in that time? Or are there some fields you are refreshing and some are user entered?

Comment: The field that user has to enter in isn't part of the binded data - I'll make other request with some binded property and what user enters (separately
)

Comment: you can use `::` bindonce directive that could help you.,

Comment: Do you have a sample json list of how your list of items look like, I can try creating a working prototype

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, when you rfresh list's model it is detected by directive's (accordion?) watcher which launch a compile, e.g. DOM rbuild of component, so there could be some ways to avoid loss of user's process:

1. right way (imho) is to move form out of the component whose model refreshes in such way
2. try to prevent refreshing while user interacts with form

   - deregister interval/timeout you use to refresh when form(or any of it's fields focused), and set interval back on submit/cancel/blur
   - try build 'shadow' model and refresh it every 20 seconds, then set watcher to it manually (in this case you will get a watcher deregister function to turn off watcher) and in this watcer refresh model, to which your accordion is linked, so again onfocus you will be able to deregister watcher.